# How to ignore all constraints and resize certain control to the fullscreen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How to ignore all constraints and resize certain control (in my case it is `UIView`) to the full screen size.

I need to do it when the user rotate its device to the landscape view so I wrote the following code:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        // NOP
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
         UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
         switch (orientation) {
             case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:

                 break;
             case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
             case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                 [self.playerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
     }];
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work -- it seems that another view at the bottom of the screen prevent `self.playerView` from fitting the whole screen:

[image]

I think that it is possible due to the constraints (for example, the `self.playerView` and the bottom view should have the same height). If so, how can I ignore these constraints and just make the `self.playerView` fullscreen then?

Comment: Just set an IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint for the height of the playerView and set that constraints .constant property in your method for detecting orientation change

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog Didn't understand you, sorry... Could you rephrase please?

Comment: see my answer for the details

Answer (score 0):

You can set an IBOutlet connection on the constraints in Interface Builder just like you would a UIButton, UILabel, etc.  In your .h file, just add two new height constraints for your playerView and the bottom view.

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *playerHeight;
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomViewHeight;
```

Then in Interface Builder, connect these outlets to your height constraints for the playerView and bottom view.

Now you can programmatically reset the constraints to a certain height in your method that detects orientation change like this:

```
// for playerView full screen
playerHeight.constant = self.view.frame.size.height;
bottomViewHeight.constant = 0;
```

Just don't forget to reset the constraints when you want them to have equal heights again:

```
// reset to equal heights
playerHeight.constant = self.view.frame.size.height/2;
bottomViewHeight.constant  = self.view.frame.size.height/2;
```

Xcode will probably complain since you have the heights set to equal, but if you remove that and programmatically set these constraints you should get the result you want.

**Edit:**

How to add a constraint, just click that button in Interface Builder, select the constraints you want to add, then click Add Constraint at the bottom of the popup:

[image]

Comment: I have only one height constraint for both views -- it define that they should have the same size

Comment: I know.. add those new height constraints

Comment: How to add these "dummy" constraints? I call them "dummy" because they shouldn't change anything on ViewController

Comment: Read my answer... thats how you add the constraints.  And they should change the layout of your view controller bc thats the whole point of adding the constraints

Comment: Didn't understand anything, sorry... Ok, that's what I have at the moment -- one constraint to set both `playerView` and `bottomView` heights proportionally to theirs superview (0.5x). I need to create two constraints instead of one for each of the views and save the existing behavior. How exactly can I do that?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?  I added a picture of how to add a constraint to my answer.. also here is a tutorial on how to use auto layout that you should probably go over before continuing since it seems you aren't really familiar with auto layout http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: I know how to add them, but then I'll have two constraints with different heights -- one says that it should have 0.5x of the parent view's height and other says that it should have height equal to 120px

Comment: No no no... get rid of that heights proportionally constraint and just add these two... then use the code I provided to set the constraints... you will need to set the constraints in viewDidLoad to both be equal, I really suggest you go over auto layout again

Comment: I think that I also need to make these views' heights equal in the `viewDidLoad` method, right?

Comment: yes, definitely.. then you can set them to whatever you want whenever you need to change them

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your requirements very well, so I am not sure if disabling the constraints is a proper solution.

However, you can activate/deactivate constraints easily.

```
NSArray<NSLayoutConstraint *> *constraints = <#constraints#>;
[NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:constraints];

// Later in code...
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:constraints];
```

Comment: Is there any way to get all constraints?

Comment: Simply `view.constraints`. You should really use public headers and documentation for this kind of stuff. :)